# using lovell/sharp with angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, node-modules, sharp

I'm trying to use `lovell/sharp` with Angular universal project, but I have an issue.

I build the server part via webpack and I added `sharp` to webpack's externals, but I got this error `Unexpected character '�' (1:2)`

so, I added `node-loader` to webpack, it builds the project and generates `dist` folder that contains `main.js` and `sharp-*.node` files
but when I run `node dist/main` I got this error:

```
Error:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

node-loader:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
//sharp-ac5709806d227d1d966f7f0b76814d78.node
```

**minimal reproduction:**

https://github.com/eng-dibo/ng-sharp-issue

1- install dependencies `npm install`

2- build the server `npm run build:server:dev`

3- serve `node dist/main`

to check the webpack configurations, check this file './webpack.server.config.js`

**issue solved**
the problem is that the webpack plugin `webpack-node-externals` cannot work with monorepos, in this case it fails to get the correct path of `package.json` file, results in node modules don't be excluded.

Comment: more details  https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2517